# Setting up ShareJS in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, sharejs

I am having trouble in setting up [meteor-share.js](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-sharejs).

Basically I followed their README.

```
{{> sharejsAce docid=docid id="editor"}}
```

What is the second `docid` here? I guess it's a helper function of the template that contains the unique name of the document that I want to synchronize?

What's the first `docid`? is this keyword for meteor-share.js?

Once I include this in a html (or template), what do I need to do in the js side (client/server?)? Is there anything I should do make the template (sharejsAce) to share text?

I do not maintain multiple editors in a page so I am not sure what I should include and exclude from the demo.

I wonder if this is simply a bug in the API. when I changed to codemirror editor it just worked. The error was saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using version 1.2.0. If this is the case, you need to force a downgrade to version 1.1.9.

You can do this by running the following command: `meteor add mizzao:sharejs-ace@=1.1.9` or by changing the version manually in the `.meteor/versions` file: `mizzao:sharejs-ace@1.1.9`.

Read more about this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-sharejs/issues/55).

---

> What is the second docid here? I guess it's a helper function of the
>   template that contains the unique name of the document that I want to
>   synchronize?

The `docid` parameter in `{{> sharejsAce docid=docid id="editor"}}` is used to specify the document which should be displayed in the editor. So, the *second* `docid` is the name of the helper function which simply returns the document's `_id` that has been selected:

```
Template.docItem.events =
  "click a": (e) ->
   e.preventDefault()
   Session.set("document", @_id)


Template.editor.helpers
  docid: -> Session.get("document")
```

> Once I include this in a html (or template), what do I need to do in
>   the js side (client/server?)? Is there anything I should do make the
>   template (sharejsAce) to share text?

If you want to mirror ShareJS data with a Meteor collection and use the ShareJS user access control, you need to create a settings file, like in the [demo](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-sharejs/tree/master/demo):

```
{
  "sharejs": {
    "options": {
      "accounts_auth": {
        "authorize": {
            "collection": "documents",
            "token_validations": {
              "or": {
                "invitedUsers": "is_in_array",
                "userId": "is_equal"
              }
            },
            "apply_on": [
              "read",
              "update",
              "create",
              "delete"
            ]
        },
        "authenticate": {
            "collection": "users",
            "token_validations": {
              "_id": "is_equal"
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I just saw the Github issue!